# Pode uma sigla violar regras de ortografia do Português?

Tags: ortografia

Recentemente eu estava lendo notícias e me deparei com a sigla [*Comsefaz*](https://comsefaz.org.br/), formada a partir de "Comitê dos Secretários da Fazenda" e imediatamente me lembrei da regra de escrita que aprendi no colégio que, para a [criação dos sons *am*, *em*, *im*, *om*, *um* antes das consoantes *P* e *B* usa-se *M* e antes das outras consoantes usa-se *N*](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-com-m-antes-de-p-e-b/).

Não deveria a sigla ser escrita como "*Consefaz*", conforme nos recomenda a boa ortografia, ainda que Comitê seja com *M* e não *N*?

Comment: Não existe nenhuma regra para acrônimos. Cada instituição faz o que bem lhe parece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Comsefaz" é um acrônimo**

> Um [**acrónimo**](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1570) é um conjunto formado pelas letras iniciais de várias palavras (ex.: EPAL), usado como uma única palavra e pronunciado não pela soletração de cada uma das letras, como as siglas, mas de forma contínua, como um nome comum (ex.: EPAL lê-se [È'pal] e não [Èpea'Èli]). Assim, pelo mesmo motivo apontado para as siglas, deverá escrever-se os PALOP (os Países Africanos de Língua Oficial Portuguesa) ou as TIC (as Tecnologias de Informação e Comunicação). Ainda em relação aos acrónimos, deve dizer-se que estes se transformam por vezes em nomes comuns (ex.: sida < Síndrome de Imunodeficiência Adquirida, cedê < CD < Compact Disc), obedecendo às regras gerais de ortografia e assumindo então as regras gerais de flexão (ex.: A sida em África é diferente das outras sidas?; Comprou vários cedês.).

**Siglas**

> Uma [**sigla**](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1570) é um conjunto formado pelas letras iniciais de várias palavras (ex.: PME = Pequena e Média Empresa), usado como uma única palavra pela soletração das letras que o compõem (ex.: P = [pe], M = [Èmi], E = [È]); como tal, pode também corresponder ao plural de uma ou mais dessas palavras, sem que as iniciais se alterem (ex.: EUA, por exemplo, é uma sigla que corresponde a um plural, Estados Unidos da América, sem que seja necessário uma marca dessa flexão). Por este motivo, não haverá razão lógica para acrescentar um esse (-s) às siglas referidas: deverá escrever-se os CD (os Compact Discs) ou as PME (as Pequenas e Médias Empresas).

**Acrônimos e siglas não são palavras e, portanto, não estão sujeitos a regras de ortografia.**